# Trying to put array of emails into codeigniter email class "to"

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, email

i'm trying to pull emails from everyone in my database for email updates. The best I have been able to achieve is it sends an email to the first person and that's it. I can't get it to insert all of them... Hoping someone has a bit more experience with this.

My model pulling emails:

```
 public function getemails ()
 {
     $this->db->select('email');
     $this->db->from('users');
     $this->db->where('status', 1);

     $query = $this->db->get();

     $results = $query->result();

     return $results;
 }
```

Then in my library where i'm compiling the email I have:

```
         if (is_array($to))
         {
                 print_r($to);
                 die;
             foreach ($to as $t)
             {
                 $this->ci->email->to($t['email']);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             $this->ci->email->to($to);
         }
```

obviously the print_r($to) and the die commands are just so i could check what's being output...

What i'm getting where it is:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [email] => name@email.com ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [email] => name2@email.com ))
```

etc...

when i put the print_r inside the foreach loop, i get:

```
stdClass Object ( [email] => name@email.com )
```

It's not printing anything after the first one... So $t->email is only returning one email which does me no good... why am I loosing all the other emails?

Comment: `$this->ci->email->to($t->email);`

Comment: I just realized that typo as well @u_mulder .... that aside, i'm not even letting it get to that part of the code because my issue already exists where i'm loosing all but the first result

Comment: What does it mean - `losing`?

Comment: I am not sure that you can call `email->to` repeatedly. Prepare array before and call one time with it. What version of php do you use?

Comment: I figured it out... it's absolute idiocy on my part... this guy put the die command inside the foreach loop instead of after it -_-

Comment: oh, i'm using 5.5...

Comment: This is my first time trying to use the email class with more than one recipient

Comment: *i'm using 5.5* - then make array by a loop and srt it as argument to `email->to`

Comment: This is what ended up doing the trick.... Thanks for the help!    





             if (is_array($to))
             {
                 $data = array();
                 foreach ($to as $t)
                 {
                     $data[] .= $t->email;
                     $this->ci->email->to($data);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 $this->ci->email->to($to);
             }

Answer (score 0):

try this Hopefully; you will get what you want to achieve

```
foreach ($to as $t) {
  echo $t->email . '<br>';
  // $this->ci->email->to($t['email']);
}
```

Comment: that got me: 

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 235

Comment: is it a matter of how my model function is pulling the data? It's returning as objects within an array... i want it to come out as one giant array...

Comment: yeah that edit still only returns the very first result... I have still lost all other emails in the array

Comment: don't use die inside foreach loop

Comment: first of all... wow... that's a no brainer and i'm feeling dumb for that one... I can't believe I struggled for.... well lets just say too long on something that stupid... THANKS! :/

Comment: This is what was needed to make it work:





             if (is_array($to))
             {
                 $data = array();
                 foreach ($to as $t)
                 {
                     $data[] .= $t->email;
                     $this->ci->email->to($data);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 $this->ci->email->to($to);
             }